# Get supplier name with only supplier id inputed using excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Before I ask , just want to let you guys know I'm a complete newbie with excel.

What I have is 4 table in 4 sheet ( transaction,drug,cashier,supplier )

[image]

Forget about **transaction and cashier**. In this case I only need **drug and supplier**.

So on drug table I have something like this

[image]

and on supplier table I have .

[image]

What I want to ask is, **is it possible when I entered the name_supplier on drug table (id_supplier column) then it will automatically search on supplier table and display the id_supplier instead?** using excel formula of course.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a task for index() with match(). match will find the matching position in a list then index will bring back the result from the target list.

Comment: You cannot do that with formulas. However, you could accomplish your task by adding the information to the autocorrect list. Perhaps adding when you open the workbook, and deleting those entries when you close the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

as @Solar Mike suggested, INDEX/MATCH can be used here.

> supplier

[image: supplier]

> cashier
>  `formula:` *INDEX(supplier!A2:A100,MATCH("Soho",supplier!B2:B100,0))*

[image: cashier]

Comment: I have tried the formula , but it is not quite what i wanted for.
What i want is everytime i type the supplier name , it will automatically change to supplier id, is it even possible ?

Comment: @BagusAmrullahFikri
I don't think that's possible through formula, you need to write Macros for it.

Comment: yea , i just finished doing some research on other site . It seems like i need a macro to do that, thank you for your answer

Comment: You can use array formula ini excel

Answer (score 0):

Use Array Formula like this:

```
=IF(
     ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B100,Supplier!A2:B100,2,FALSE)),
     "",
     VLOOKUP(B2:B100,Supplier!A2:B100,2,FALSE)
   )
```

[image]